# node-sqlite3 select columns from multiple tables

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm using node-sqlite3 installed from npm. This question relates to that specific plugin. I am running the following via node:

node select.js

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('foods.db');

db.serialize(function() {

    db.each(
"select foods.name, food_types.name from foods, food_types where foods.type_id=food_types.id limit 10;"

        , function(err, row){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(row);
    });

})
db.close();
```

this code returns

```
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
{ name: 'Bakery' }
```

However using sqlite3

```
select foods.name, food_types.name from foods, food_types where foods.type_id=food_types.id limit 10;
```

returns (with .headers on, .mode column,)

```
name        name      
----------  ----------
Bagels      Bakery    
Bagels, ra  Bakery    
Bavarian C  Bakery    
Bear Claws  Bakery    
Black and   Bakery    
Bread (wit  Bakery    
Butterfing  Bakery    
Carrot Cak  Bakery    
Chips Ahoy  Bakery    
Chocolate   Bakery
```

Am I using the node-sqlite3 npm module incorrectly, I would expect to see something like

```
{ name: 'Bakery', name: 'Bagels' }
{ name: 'Bakery',  name: 'Bagels, ra'}
{ name: 'Bakery', name: 'Bavarian C' }
{ name: 'Bakery', name: 'Bear Claws' }
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite module cannot give you back a results object with the same key twice; one value will have to override the other.  You can get around this by assigning a different name to one of the columns using `as` in your SQL:

```
select foods.name as name_food, food_types.name as name_type from ...
```

The above will give you a result like the following:

```
{ name_type: 'Bakery', name_food: 'Bagels' }
{ name_type: 'Bakery', name_food: 'Bagels, ra'}
{ name_type: 'Bakery', name_food: 'Bavarian C' }
{ name_type: 'Bakery', name_food: 'Bear Claws' }
...
```